# React: How to display mapped array after button press?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping

I'm new to react and struggling to get this to work. I can display a mapped array, but I am trying to update the array, map it, then display it.  Can't figure out how to get the mapped array to display after it's updated?

Tried to add the mappedItems to my function also, but that didn't seem to solve it. TIA.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const itemsList = ['item1','item2'];

class RecieveInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            list: itemsList
        }
    }

    render(){
        const pressedEnter = event => {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            this.state.list.push(event.target.value);
            console.log(this.state.list);
            }
        }  
        
        const mappedItemsList = this.state.list.map( (listItem, i) => <li>{this.state.list[i]}</li> )
     
        return(
            <div>
                <input 
                type ="text" 
                id="textInput"
                placeholder="Enter Item Here"
                onKeyPress={pressedEnter}
                />
                <ol className='ol'>{mappedItemsList}</ol>
             </div>
        )
    }
}  

export default RecieveInput
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83efy.png)

Comment: You should not mutate the state directly `this.state.list.push(event.target.value);`. This should be done using the provided `this.setState` i.e. `this.setState({ list: [...list, event.target.value ]});`. React uses `this.setState` to know when state has been updated and the `shouldComponentUpdate` method of a class component only does a shallow comparison on references so if you do not create a new array when setting the state React will not see it as a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The `pressedEnter` callback should be declared in the component, not the `render` function. It should also not mutate the state object by pushing into the state array.

## Solution

Move the `pressedEnter` handler into the component and use `this.setState` to enqueue an update. You need to shallow copy the existing state and append the new element into it so your `list` state is a new array reference.

```
const pressedEnter = event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      list: prevState.list.concat(value), // or [...prevState.list, value]
    }));
  }
}
```